# am I using it right, the word 3 or 2?

Tags: grammar, meaning

can I write it as "Being a part of a family with 3 siblings " does it imply we are 4 brothers/sisters or 3?
we are 3 children in our family here.

Comment: '2' and '3' are not 'words' when written, they are **figures**. We normally write numbers smaller than (often) 11 as words, like this: I am one of **three** siblings in my family. I have **two** siblings. If you said that you **have** three siblings, that means there **are** four siblings in you family.

Comment: How many siblings do you think there are in a family with three siblings? How many siblings do you think there are in a family where one family member has three siblings?